# Would nuns address each other with ‘du’ only — even when speaking to their superiors?

Tags: word-usage, history, personal-pronoun

I am learning German and I understand the general *du* versus *Sie* rules, but I had a question as it pertains to religion. I was watching the German language film *Vision — From the life of Hildegard von Bingen*. For those who don’t know, she was a Benedictine sister, Abbess, theologian, etc. from the 12<sup>th</sup> century. I noticed that the sisters and brothers used *du* with each other and even with their superiors in the order — the Abbot and the Magistra.

Do the standard social rules and respecting hierarchy completely change when one is in the religious orders?

Something peculiar to the time period perhaps — 12<sup>th</sup> century?

Is this somehow related to the fact that God is addressed with Du and that carries over here?

Comment: They probably spoke Latin originally, which has no formal way of address. That said, rules in a tight-knit community might differ. To give a random example, officers in the Austrian often use "Du" with each other. The same is true for students, fraternities, etc. Don't overthink it. Use "Sie" when in doubt.

Comment: @Ingmar: Wieso im Zweifel "Sie" benutzen? Und was hat die Frage mit Latein zu tun? Amerikanische Filme kennen auch keine Sie/Du-Unterscheidung und werden dennoch mit Sie/Du, je nach Beziehung, übersetzt. Kennst Du Klosterfilme, in denen sich die Nonnen sietzen? Du selbst bringst beispielhafte Ausnahmen für innerorganisatorische Konventionen vor.

Comment: Sie ist der "Normalfall", von dem abgewichen werden kann. Insb. als Ausländer ist es kein Problem jmd. zu siezen, um dann zu hören "hier auf der Uni duzen wir uns alle" oä, statt umgekehrt. Im Lateinischen (wie, das ist richtig, im Englischen) gibt es diese Unterscheidung nicht (Englisch: nicht mehr), so dass hier die Macher oder Übersetzer des Films entscheiden müssen. Ob sie das richtig getan haben oder nicht, sei dahingestellt. Zu den intramuralen Anrederkonventionen, in Klöstern oder anderswo, kann ich leider nichts eigenes beitragen.

Comment: @Ingmar: Du musst mich adressieren, wenn Du willst, dass ich über Deinen Kommentar benachrichtigt werde. Da ich nicht erwarte, dass Frank einem Kloster beitreten will, wird er das "Du" eher in einem Text benutzen, in dem sich Nonnen unterhalten, so dass vorsichtige Höflichkeit nicht meine primäre Strategie wäre, sondern mutmaßliche Korrektheit. Der Film Vision ist übrigens ein dt. Film, so dass Fragen der Übersetzung Fehl am Platz sind.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

*Du* vs. *Sie* is a new invention. In the past, people addressed each other with the whole range of pronouns, depending on rank. But *du* was pretty common the whole time.

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher dass sich Nonnen und Brüder in allen Klöstern untereinander duzen um die Gleichheit untereinander zu betonen. Außerdem glaube ich kaum, dass es in Ordensgemeinschaften je anders war. Wann soll denn die neue Erfindung gewesen sein? Wenn im Film nicht insgesamt im Deutsch des 12. Jhr. gesprochen wird - und das kann ich mir kaum vorstellen - wieso sollte dann bei der Anrede eine Ausnahme gemacht worden sein?

Comment: Es ist etwas seltsam, das als *neu* darzustellen, selbst wenn diese Höflichkeitsform relativ zur guten Hildegard (die ja auch noch Mittelhochdeutsch gesprochen hat) jüngeren Datums ist.

Comment: Das Siezen gibt es erst seit ca. 1700. Davor wurde *du* oder *ihr* (mit welchselnder Bedeutung der Rangfolge) verwendet, bei Untergebenen auch *er*.

Comment: *Neu* ist eher die Nachkriegszeit, und damit ist nicht der Dreißigjährige Krieg gemeint. Ein bißchen weiter hättest du das schon ausführen können, wenn auch das Duzen im Mittelalter tatsächlich üblich(er) war. Zwei kurze Sätze sind etwas mager als Antwort, zumal du es nur eine partielle ist.

Comment: Die Frage drehte sich um das 12. Jahrhundert. 500 Jahre später gab es das "Sie" noch nicht. Das ist deutlich mehr als die 300 Jahre, die zwischen 1700 und heute liegen.

Answer (score 3):

It does not have to do with the fact that God is addressed with *du.*

*Du* forms indicate a certain closeness between those who use it, if it is not a grown-up addressing a child. This closeness is clearest when *du* is used between family memberes, but also often groups of colleagues, club mates, drinking buddies, fellow party memberes etc. use *du* with each other. This can be seen as an attempt of reducing the distance between the members of a group and likewise increasing the distance to outsiders.

For members of the same nunnery, this ‘group feeling’ would definitely apply. They have come together to worship God (group feeling), by doing so they may feel superiour compared to the outside world (create distance), and in principle they would all have started as equals. Nowadays, it is custom for all sisters to address each other as *sister (Schwester),* whether it is the magistra or just the nun from next-door. Using *Schwester* and not using *du* would sound strange to most ears. It also helps that Jesus is typically addressed with *du*.

However, in the Middle ages the magistra was often referred to as *mother (Mutter)* which would allow for a more diverse addressing; specifically, using *Mutter* and *Ihr* (a more archaic form of *Sie)* does not sound as strange. Without having seen the film, I cannot say whether the language used was stylised to sound like 12<sup>th</sup> or modern-day.